# Probability that $\text{det}(A)$ is an even number.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I'm struggling to solve the following problem:

If a matrix $A$ is chosen randomly in the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $A\in\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, what is the probability that $\text{det}(A)$ is an even number?

How can I solve this problem, why is the probability a finite number, even thought I'm dealing with an infinite set. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe considering matrices with entries in $[-N,N]$ and let $N\to\infty$ is one way to define a probability.

Comment: The parity of the determinant is determined by the parities of the entries. So you only need to choose the four parities at random. Then $10$ of the possible $2^4=16$ choices of parities yield an even determinant.

Comment: @lalaland You are completely right to question this.  There is no such thing as a matrix chosen uniformly at random in the set of all integer $2\times 2$ matrices, so calling this a “probability” is an abuse of terminology (albeit a commonly accepted one) that needed to be clarified.  I prefer the term “limiting probability” for the interpretation suggested by Seewoo Lee, but in this case there is also a finitistic interpretation that is more natural (the one used in both answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A=\left(\matrix{a&b\\c&d}\right)\in\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. $\text{det}(A)=2n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ iff $\text{det}(A')=0$, with
$$
A'=\left(\matrix{a_2&b_2\\c_2&d_2}\right)\in\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z}_2),
$$
where the coefficients are reduced modulo 2.

The matrices with zero determinant in $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ are:
\begin{align}
\left(\matrix{0&0\\0&0}\right),&&\left(\matrix{0&1\\0&0}\right),&&\left(\matrix{1&0\\0&0}\right),&&\left(\matrix{0&0\\1&0}\right),&&\left(\matrix{0&0\\0&1}\right),\\
\left(\matrix{1&1\\0&0}\right),&&\left(\matrix{1&0\\1&0}\right),&&\left(\matrix{0&1\\0&1}\right),&&\left(\matrix{0&0\\1&1}\right),&&\left(\matrix{1&1\\1&1}\right).\\
\end{align}

So the required probability is
$$
\frac{10}{|\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)|}=\frac{10}{|\mathbb{Z}_2|^{2\cdot 2}}=\frac{10}{16}=\frac{5}{8}.
$$

Comment: This works _assuming_ that for a given $B\in \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z_2})$ the probability that $A'=B$ is $1/16$. Ie, it's assuming that $A'$ is uniformly distributed...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we are dealing with [simple random samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample), since the determinant of the matrix $ad-bc$ is even if $ad$ and $bc$ are both even or both odd, we obtain

$$P=\overbrace{\left(\frac14\right)^2}^{\color{blue}{\text{both odd}}}+\overbrace{\left(1-\left(\frac12\right)^2\right)^2}^{\color{red}{\text{both even}}}=\frac1{16}+\frac9{16}=\frac 5 8$$

Otherwise, as noticed by David C. Ullrich, we need to specify a probability distribution for $A$.

Comment: This _assumes_ (i) the entries are independent, (ii) for each entry, the probability that it is even is $1/2$. Neither of those is given, and neither follows from what's given

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for your comment. I understand your point of view but I think that it a too much harsh in this case. Indeed I think that the statement "chosen randomly" in this case, without any other specific indication, can be interpreted as a ["simple random sample"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample). Of course it would be better state clearly this assumption but as you noticed it seems really reasonable to be adopted here. I'll add something on that to make it clear.

Comment: No, it's obviously impossible for this to be a "simple random sample". From the definition you linked to: "each individual has the same probability of being chosen at any stage during the sampling process". In other words, a "simple random sample" is just a sample from a uniform distribution, and there is no uniform distribution on an infinite set.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "random matrix". Or rather, there are infinitely many different things that the phrase "random matrix" might mean - before you can answer any questions about the probability of this or that given a random matrix you need to *specify* a *probability distribution* for $A$.

The two other answers both entail (reasonable) unstated assumptions about this distribution. For a detailed discussion of a similarly poorly-posed problem see
[Bertrand's paradox.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability))